# Default attribute when merging two polygons in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, fields-attributes, merge

When merging two polygons in ArcMap 10.3, it appears that the new polygon always inherits the attributes of the larger (by area) of the two input polygons, unless otherwise specified. Is this by design, or by coincidence?

Comment: The Editor toolbar Merge tool uses the attributes of whatever feature you click on in the list of features selected.  If you don't click it uses the first feature in the list.  The probability is that the first feature will be the largest since whenever you split a polygon or polyline, the largest portion always retains the original ObjectID, and the features in the list are sorted by ObjectID.

Comment: If you get a chance @RichardFairhurst I think it would be good if you could write a short answer that need be little more than a copy/paste of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The Editor toolbar Merge tool uses the attributes of whatever feature you click on in the list of features selected. If you don't click, it uses the first feature in the list. The probability is that the first feature will be the largest, since whenever you split a polygon or polyline, the largest portion always retains the original ObjectID, and the features in the list are sorted by ObjectID.

(Added as an answer so that the question status can be changed to Answered)